# Where can I learn theoretical aspect of Reinforcement learning

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning

Every RL paper has a section with some finite sample analysis/error bound/ convergence proofs. I have difficulty fully understanding such proofs and coming up with my own analysis for my personal projects. Can anyone suggest books/courses where I can develop my skills to do such work?

Comment: There is an open textbook on RL theory (work in progress right now) which you can find by googling RL theory book.

Comment: The one from the Cornell Prof.? I will give it a try.

Comment: It’s by Sham Kakade, Nan Jiang, Wen Sun, and Alekh Agarwal.